# Modiy axios request 'data' field into 'body'

Tags: node.js, api, post, request, axios

I'm trying to create a POST request using axios to a Notification API. So this Notification API have been developed before thus I cannot change anything related to it.
It accepts the request more or less like below.

I need to have the request body in the field called `body` as shown below. However, axios sends the request body in the field called `data` rather than `body`

```
Expected request 
{
  "head": {
    ...
  },
  "body":{  
     "publicUserId":"abcd",
     "merchantId":"123888",
    }
  },
}
```

My request composed automatically by axios:

```
Axios request 
{
  "head": {
    ...
  },
  "data":{  
     "publicUserId":"abcd",
     "merchantId":"123888",
    }
  },
}
```

I did try searching for how to alter the request body field name to `body` instead of `data` but I'm pretty sure I haven't found the solution. Maybe if anyone here has some workarounds, I'd be glad to try.

Should any details need to be provided, please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: it's up to the server to parse the incoming request, and in most cases, it's `body`! So regardless of what Axios is actually sending

Comment: But how handle it from my side? I cannot change the `data` field into `body` on my request due to using axios. And my Backend only accepts `body` rather that `data` :/

Comment: can you paste the error returned by the backend when sending `data`

Comment: {
   "head":{
      
   },
   "body":{
      "resultInfo":{
         "resultCode":"MSG_PARSE_ERR",
         "resultId":"00000",
         "resultStat":"F",
         "resultMsg":"MSG_PARSE_ERR"
      }
   }
} -- they give me this.